# How to check ov JTextField in actionperformed

Tags: java, jtextfield

I have a JTextField that a user will enter a number.

How is it that I check whether or not the number that they entered is greater than 0?

I am very new to this so sorry if it is a bit obvious to you.

Here is my code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;


public class TaxiFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {


      private JLabel L1 = new JLabel("Number of Taxis:");
      private JLabel L2 = new JLabel("Type an integer and press enter");
      private JTextField t1 = new JTextField ("            ");




    public TaxiFrame() {
        super("This is the Frame");
        setSize(500, 300);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));

         JPanel p = new JPanel();     


         p.setOpaque(false);
         p.add(L1);
         getContentPane().
         add("South", p);

          p.setOpaque(false);
          p.add(t1);
          getContentPane().
          add("South", p);

          p.setOpaque(false);
          p.add(L2);
          getContentPane().
          add("South", p);

        setVisible(true);

        t1.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TaxiFrame();
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        if (e.getSource() == t1)
        {

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Excellent, Just the bit of code I needed :D thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the text from the JTextField. Calling `getText()` on the JTextField will do this. Check the [JTextField tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) for more on this.
2. Parse the String to an int with `Integer.parseInt(...)`.
3. Check if > 0.

In the future, break down all such questions into their individual steps, and try to solve each step at a time. Doing this will help you find your solutions by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;


public class TaxiFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {


      private JLabel L1 = new JLabel("Number of Taxis:");
      private JLabel L2 = new JLabel("Type an integer and press enter");
      private JTextField t1 = new JTextField ("            ");




    public TaxiFrame() {
        super("This is the Frame");
        setSize(500, 300);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));

         JPanel p = new JPanel();     


         p.setOpaque(false);
         p.add(L1);
         getContentPane().
         add("South", p);

          p.setOpaque(false);
          p.add(t1);
          getContentPane().
          add("South", p);

          p.setOpaque(false);
          p.add(L2);
          getContentPane().
          add("South", p);

        setVisible(true);

        t1.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TaxiFrame();
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        if (e.getSource() == t1)
        {
            if(Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().trim()) > 0)
            {
                //Do here
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 use "textfieldfilter" by making class JTextFieldFilter
```

[JTextField limiting character amount input and accepting numeric only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793030/jtextfield-limiting-character-amount-input-and-accepting-numeric-only)
 and in  @Override
  public void insertString function provide your condition

hope it help