# JFormattedTextField and BigDecimals

Tags: java, jtextfield, bigdecimal

```
private JFormattedTextField floatingText = new JFormattedTextField();

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
NumberFormatter dnff = new NumberFormatter(df);
DefaultFormatterFactory factory = new DefaultFormatterFactory(dnff);
floatingText.setFormatterFactory(factory);
```

It works perfectly when I enter small numbers such as 1.23 but when I enter BigDecimals like 9.99999999 it rounds it off to 10. What can I do so Formatter can accept BigDecimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the min and max digits to display through methods on `DecimalFormat`. So:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(20);
```

There are other methods on there to play around with too.

Comment: I made it maximum 16 but when exceeds the maximum it rounds off again how can I make it so that he wont accept any inputs greater than 16 digits?

Comment: ah ok, that's a bit trickier.  You can use a `DocumentFilter` for that.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793030/jtextfield-limiting-character-amount-input-and-accepting-numeric-only